# Adding column with values from one dataframe to another based on same datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a big dataframe of datetime and values so I will just be taking a sample dataframe called df1

```
DateTime            Values
2020-12-26 14:00:00 439.0
2020-12-26 14:00:00 441.0
2020-12-26 14:00:00 461.0
2020-12-27 08:00:00 536.0
2020-12-27 08:00:00 547.0
2020-12-27 08:00:00 484.0
2020-12-27 08:00:00 497.0
2020-12-27 14:00:00 491.0
2020-12-27 14:00:00 512.0
2020-12-27 14:00:00 529.0
2020-12-27 14:00:00 436.0
```

and I have another full dataframe df 2

```
DateTime            Trend   
2020-12-18 14:00    no trend    
2020-12-19 08:00    no trend    
2020-12-19 14:00    no trend    
2020-12-21 08:00    no trend        
2020-12-21 14:00    no trend    
2020-12-22 08:00    no trend    
2020-12-22 14:00    decreasing  
2020-12-23 08:00    no trend    
2020-12-23 14:00    no trend    
2020-12-24 08:00    no trend    
2020-12-24 14:00    no trend    
2020-12-25 08:00    no trend    
2020-12-25 14:00    decreasing  
2020-12-26 08:00    no trend
2020-12-26 14:00    decreasing  
2020-12-27 08:00    no trend    
2020-12-27 14:00    no trend
```

I am trying to create a new column df1[Trend] and assign the trend values based on the right date time

The result should be like this

```
DateTime            Values    Trend
2020-12-26 14:00:00 439.0     decreasing
2020-12-26 14:00:00 441.0     decreasing
2020-12-26 14:00:00 461.0     decreasing
2020-12-27 08:00:00 536.0     no trend
2020-12-27 08:00:00 547.0     no trend
2020-12-27 08:00:00 484.0     no trend
2020-12-27 08:00:00 497.0     no trend
2020-12-27 14:00:00 491.0     no trend
2020-12-27 14:00:00 512.0     no trend
2020-12-27 14:00:00 529.0     no trend
2020-12-27 14:00:00 436.0     no trend
```

Is there anyway I could it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df1.merge(df2)

              DateTime  Values       Trend
0  2020-12-26 14:00:00   439.0  decreasing
1  2020-12-26 14:00:00   441.0  decreasing
2  2020-12-26 14:00:00   461.0  decreasing
3  2020-12-27 08:00:00   536.0    no trend
4  2020-12-27 08:00:00   547.0    no trend
5  2020-12-27 08:00:00   484.0    no trend
6  2020-12-27 08:00:00   497.0    no trend
7  2020-12-27 14:00:00   491.0    no trend
8  2020-12-27 14:00:00   512.0    no trend
9  2020-12-27 14:00:00   529.0    no trend
10 2020-12-27 14:00:00   436.0    no trend
```

---

EDIT

You're getting

> ValueError: You are trying to merge on datetime64[ns] and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

because `df1["DateTime"]` is a datetime column but `df2["DateTime"]` is a `str` column then you can't merge. To fix it convert `df2["DateTime"]` to datetime with [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df2['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.DateTime)
```

Comment: I got this error when I do it. 
ValueError: You are trying to merge on datetime64[ns] and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
However by doing pd.concat if will just combine two dataframes horizontally and result in the remaining to have nan values which is not what I am looking for\

Comment: Convert into datetime column`df2['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.DateTime)`.

Comment: @DDM check it now :P

Comment: Thanks alot yes its due to the object type

Comment: @DDM Nice! happy coding :)